# How to pass variable from stateful widget class? - flutter

Tags: flutter, state

I have a string that contains an information that was passed from previous classes. But i need to use that variable in the state class.

Class of stateful widget that contains the information (String text):

```
class CreateLevelScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  String text;
  CreateLevelScreen({Key key, @required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CreateLevelState();
}
```

State class of stateful widget to retrieve that information text too.

```
class _CreateLevelState extends State<CreateLevelScreen> {

   //need to pass text in here to use it too.
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you say

```
class _CreateLevelState extends State<CreateLevelScreen>
```

it means `_CreateLevelState` will manage the state of `CreateLevelScreen`

so the variables are directly accessible as `widget.<variable_name>`

thus you have `widget.text`to be used in `_CreateLevelState` class if there is a variable `text` in your `CreateLevelScreen` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `text` in `_CreateLevelState` using `widget.text`.